# DataBufferInt cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, graphics

I'm currently working on learning some game development with Java. I'm working on the display and drawing pixels on the screen, I'm kind of a noob when it comes to this stuff. So I'm not quite sure what's wrong.

So in Eclipse, I have a Display class, a Render class, and a Screen class.

I have an array called pixels. I am trying to set pixels like this:

```
pixels = ((DataBufferInt).img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

However Eclipse give an error, underlining "DataBufferInt" in red. Saying that DataBufferInt cannot be resolved to a variable. I have imported the DataBufferInt class. Also img is a BufferedImage object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a dot in a wrong place:

```
pixels = ((DataBufferInt) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

Also make sure it's actually `DataBufferInt` there or you'll get `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Ohh I see, I thought there was supposed to be a dot between ((DataBufferInt) and img. Thanks a ton.